# FOSUserBundle & Symfony 3.4 : login page show 404 page in production mode

Tags: php, symfony, routes, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I'm using FOSUserBundle v2.1.2 with Symfony 3.4 and every thing is working fine in dev mode but in prod, web/app.php/login shows 404 page. I've tried to solve it by doing the following methods in vain:

- `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
- Remove var/cache : `rm -r var/cache`
- set in `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` in `web/app.php`.
- `composer update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` : successfully updated.

Notice: both `/web/login` and `/web/app.php/login` are not working

[image]

Comment: It should be just `/login` and  not `/web/app.php/login`. The `web` folder is the site root, and in prod environment the `app.php` part is removed.

Comment: Yes I know but even /login is not working.

Comment: try dev mode(web/app_dev.php/login), so you can see the error. if this is not working for you then check symfony logs / server log.

Comment: As I've mention in my post, there is no problem with dev mode and I allready check the prod.log the result is simply normal message as such "404: no rout found for the path /login..."